# How to update the latest row in MySQL table

Tags: joomla-2.5, joomla-api, database, mysql, update

The table **#__virtuemart_order_histories** stores the orders with their **virtuemart_order_id**s and every order has the records with their own **virtuemart_order_history_id**s. I need to update the latest record in the range of certain order. Now I have the code:

```
$order_id = 1028;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$fields = array($db->quoteName('order_status_code') . " = " . $db->quote('U'));
$conditions = array($db->quoteName('virtuemart_order_id') . " = " . $order_id);
$query->update($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_order_histories'))->set($fields)->where($conditions)->order($db->quoteName('virtuemart_order_history_id') . ' DESC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute($query);
```

But it doesn't work how I need — it updates ALL the records of certain order and not only the latest one. How should I specify the condition of getting only the latest record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use limit to run on first row found. Since you order it by `virtuemart_order_history_id`, it will be latest record.

Instead of

```
$db->setQuery($query);
```

use

```
$db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);
```

Second argument is `$offset`, third is `$limit`.

Comment: LIMIT works in MySQL, Joomla supports other databases as well like Oracle which don't know this.

Comment: Of course, how I forgot that. Thanks @Nagarjun. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways which you can do database independent way (Joomla recommended).

A. Set limit on query (works with Joomla 3.x only)

```
$query->setLimit($limit, $offset);
e.g. $query->setLimit(1, 0);
```

B. Set limit while assigning query to db object (Works with Joomla 2.5 & 3.x)

```
$db->setQuery($query, $offset, $limit);
e.g. $db->setQuery($query, 0, 1);
```

Comment: `setLimit` is only available for Joomla 3.x, not 2.5

Comment: Also, it should be `$db->setQuery(0, 1)`. First is offset, second is the limit.